# Creating regular users in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

How can I create regular, non-admin users in CouchDB?

Comment: You might be interested in this wiki article. http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_create_users_via_script

Comment: What are the naming rules? I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Can a username be an email address?

Comment: Usernames can be absolutely any UTF-8 string. For example, that's the reason why `couchdb_peruser` needs to hash usernames to make database names.

There is a couple of restrictions that you can find in [the design doc for the _users database](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/103a0624f309ea0d796176a55eb5faea68f26047/src/couch/include/couch_js_functions.hrl#L147):
- usernames cannot begin with an underscore `_`
- usernames cannot contain a colon `:`

_(It's still hard to find an answer to this online in 2019)_

Answer (score 114):

First you put the user in `_users` database. The ID of the document must be `org.couchdb.user:username`, e.g.

With CouchDB 1.2.0 or later use this:

```
{
    "_id": "org.couchdb.user:dbreader",
    "name": "dbreader",
    "type": "user",
    "roles": [],
    "password": "plaintext_password"
}
```

CouchDB will hash & salt the password for you on the server side and save the values in the fields `password_sha` and `salt` (see below).

With CouchDB < 1.2.0 the user document needs to look like this:

```
{
    "_id": "org.couchdb.user:dbreader",
    "name": "dbreader",
    "type": "user",
    "roles": [],
    "salt": "54935938852dd34f92c672ab31e397cedaf0946d",
    "password_sha": "42253ea4461a604f967813aaff90b139d7018806"
}
```

Note that CouchDB 1.3.0 and later will use PBKDF2 instead of aha & salt for hashing the password.

Then you can create per database authentication by creating document with id _security in specific database which is not versioned, e.g.

```
{
    "admins": {
        "names": ["dbadmin"],
        "roles": ["editor"]
    },
    "readers": {
        "names": ["dbreader"],
        "roles": ["reader"]
    }
}
```

This means that there are 2 users in `_users` besides the admin *dbadmin* and *dbreader*. That should do in case you are too lazy to read the document that has already been suggested.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out the naming conventions. Are there any restrictions on what the username can be? Other than the prefix org.couchdb.user:

Comment: so user passwords are seen by everyone when you store them ? and how to hash them ?

Comment: @astroanu: You post it in clear text, yes, but when it comes back to you from the server (and every GET request thereafter), it's only the salted and hashed version of the password that gets returned.

Comment: What about Cloudant?

Answer (score 21):

The CouchDB documentation has a short article about the [security features](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html#creating-a-new-user) of CouchDB, and it includes a section on how to create a new user.

Comment: This is correct. The short answer to IDanil's question is, "create a document in the `_users` database." However your link explains all the details and implications.

Answer (score -13):

I think you have to put a web framework in front to do this the way many sites do. Couchdb admin roles do not work on a record by record basis, so if you create a reader who can read the profiles or account table they can read record.

Comment: This posting requires an explanation into why so many people down voted it. CouchDB allows you to create users by sending a JSON object to one of the REST-APIs endpoints. The structure of this document has been layed out by Gjorgji in his posting.

Comment: @SomeDutchGuy I guess because you don't "have to put a web framework in front of it.." ‍♂️