# CouchDB: How to set/get user's password hash?

Tags: security, authentication, couchdb

I want to synchronize the passwords from a MySQL database user table with the CouchDB _users database. From what I can see, on CouchDB it is not possible to look up a user's password hash through the HTTP API. How would you go about manually retrieving and modifying the CouchDB user password hashes?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684749/how-to-create-users-in-couchdb-not-admin) seems to cover SETTING the password, but not GETTING.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get the *original* password, only the SHA1 checksum and input hash.

You can simply fetch them directly from the user's document in the `_users` database.

```
curl http://localhost:5984/_users/_all_docs?startkey=\"org.couchdb.user\"\&include_docs=true
```

For each row, you have the `salt` and `password_sha` value.

Comment: Is there any reason why the hashes wouldn't be returned? I executed this same query on my v1.0.1 server (Ubuntu 11.04 package) and received all attributes for users EXCEPT the password items. I also tried this on futon while logged in as admin. The user's password hash and salt were not listed.

Comment: I think the admin user does *not* get a password hash or salt, because those are stored in the .ini config files instead. Other normal users do have a hash and salt value, in Apache CouchDB.

Comment: admin users *do* get a hash and salt, but it's stored only in the .ini file, and therefore not readable via the _users db. You can fetch it from /_config/admins/<adminname> though.

Comment: One more thing to verify before I accept: Is there an "official" way to create users besides posting a user document to the _user db? It kind of scares me that the system treats admin user docs differently. Are there any other gotchas to regular user documents?

Comment: The admin password values are the only exception I can think of. The official way to create normal users is definitely documents in the `_users` database. The official way to update them is definitely to change the values in that doc.