# CouchDB add user without predefined admin

Tags: couchdb

I'm just want to create a standalone application with CouchDB back-end, but I don't know if I can add a new (ordinary) user without using admin credentials. 
In the documentation I just got information about creating an admin user and existing user's permissions:

> Only administrators may browse list of all documents (GET
>   /_users/_all_docs)   Only administrators may listen to changes feed
>   (GET /_users/_changes)
>
> Only administrators may execute design functions like views, shows and
>   others
>
> There is a special design document _auth that cannot be modified
>
> Every document except the design documents represent registered
>   CouchDB users and belong to them
>
> Users may only access (GET /_users/org.couchdb.user:Jan) or modify
>   (PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user:Jan) documents that they own

[Here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/intro/security.html) is the relevant part of documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

**YES, you can**

Makes no sense in a registration if you have to use admin credentials to create your account. Anyway, here is an example:

https://serverfault.com/questions/742184/couchdb-user-creation-without-authentication-standard-behavior

In this topic also can be useful this articol:
http://www.staticshin.com/programming/easy-user-accounts-management-with-couchdb

One more tip:
[Creating regular users in CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684749/creating-regular-users-in-couchdb)