# CouchDB Fauxton Web Interface: how to not require login to create/edit documents

Tags: authentication, couchdb, couchdb-2.0, fauxton

I am trying to set up a CouchDB instance to:

- Not require login at **web user interface** when to create/edit/delete documents for random people who go to `http://my_couchdb:5984`
- Prevent random people from making admin level changes

  - Ex: modify design docs, add users or remove pre-existing users

Basically, I would like random people to be something like the `members` described here: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/api/database/security.html#api-db-security

What settings are necessary to make this happen?  Do they live in `etc/local.ini`?

I would not like to use cookies or individual user databases.

---

**How I Set It Up**

I configured CouchDB to have an admin user, `boss`.

I also made a database `bananas`: http://my_couchdb:5984/_utils/#database/bananas/_all_docs

---

**What I've Tried So Far**

Manipulating `require_valid_user` in both `httpd` and `chttpd` inside `etc/local.ini` ([source](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/require_valid_user)) did not work for me, maybe I didn't quite do it right

Per [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/941399/514234), I tried adding the admin user `boss` to Permissions --> Admins --> Users of both `_users` db and `bananas` db, and it failed to achieve my desired result.

I then removed both of these, and the response of `curl $HOST/bananas/_security` is now `{}`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6418670/11163122) talks about creating a low-permissions user, but doesn't talk about how to bypass log in.

The below `authentication_handler` works, but I don't want an Admin Party, so I need a better method.

```
[chttpd]
authentication_handlers = {couch_httpd_auth, null_authentication_handler}
```

---

****Update****

As pointed out by @uminder, out of the box it seems to be possible to make documents without credentials.  I ran the following command from a second machine:

```
curl -X PUT http://my_couchdb:5984/bananas/test -d '{ "name": "test document" }'
```

And can then view (but not edit) the document by going here:

http://my_couchdb:5984/bananas/test

[image: Going to URL direct]

(Please ignore that the hostname is not actually `my_couchdb`)

What I need is to **use a web UI, *without login*, to edit that document**.  Currently, the UI is Fauxton.  Here is what I do:

1. Go here: http://my_couchdb:5984/_utils/#database/bananas/test
2. It redirects to login page here: http://my_couchdb:5984/_utils/#login

[image: Redirect to login page]

**How can I not get redirected to login, and just be able to edit the document using the Web UI?**

[image: What I Want]

---

**Setup Information**

- CouchDB Version: `2.3.1`
- OS: `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`

Please let me know what other information is needed to arrive at a solution!  I am new to configuring CouchDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just locally installed `CouchDB` ([Single Node Setup](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/setup/single-node.html)) on Windows 10. Then I created an `admin user` and a `bananas` database in `Fauxton`.

Using `curl`, I was able to `create`, `update` and `delete` documents in `bananas` database without providing any credencials.

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/bananas/1 -d '{ "name": "doc 1"  }' 
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/bananas/1 -d '{ "name": "doc 2", "_rev": "1-5cd56a944d3d59a44613269396365431" }'
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:5984/bananas/1?rev=3-2b34329467970cc792cee5931a68ca2e
```

When trying to create a design document (an index) in `bananas` however, I got an "unauthorized" error with reason "You are not a db or server admin."

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/bananas/_design/name_idx -d '{ "index": { "fields": ["name"] } }
```

The result was exactly the same when I installing `CouchDB` on another computer within the same subnet. It seems that in these cases, a newly installed `CouchDB` with default settings just behaves the way you wish, at least when referring to the tile of your answer.

If I had to make my `CouchDB` accessible through a public URL, I would try to change the default security object and enable `CORS` in the `local.ini` file.

```
[couchdb]
default_security = everyone 

[httpd]
enable_cors = true

[cors]
origins = *
methods = GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
credentials = false
```

**Bypassing Web-Interface Login**

I don't think Fauxton can be configured to bypass the login page in order to allow anonymous users to directly create, update or delete documents. You would have to create a fork of the [couchdb-fauxton](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton) project and change the code to fit your needs.

Alternatively you could write you own web-interface (Angular, React, Vue.js ...) that internally uses an existing user for authentication but hides this to the end user.

Comment: Hello @uminder and thank you so much for pointing out that one can use `curl` to make/edit documents, out of the box.  Without making the `local.ini` changes you suggested, I realized it was already possible to remotely change the documents.  One can also seemingly view them in web interface by not including `_utils/#database/` in the URL.

Comment: I updated my question to encompass more exactly what I wanted, which is to be able to use web UI without requiring login.  In doing so, it made the question much more verbose.  @uminder, do you know of a way to not require login to use web UI?

Comment: I updated my answer with section "Bypassing Web-Interface Login"

Comment: Consider using Photon (https://github.com/ermouth/couch-photon) instead of Fauxton. Photon can be easily configured to allow operations w/o user authentication, also Photon is waaaay more comfortable.

Comment: Thank you @uminder for pointing out that login in Fauxton cannot be bypassed, and thank you for the in depth answer in general.

Comment: And thank you @ermouth for pointing out that there's a workaround!