# when I am trying to create user in couchdb its giving me error {"error":"forbidden","reason":"Doc ID must be of the form org.couchdb.user:name"}

Tags: couchdb

earlier I asked the question and I got the theoretical solution but then I am trying to create a user it's giving me an error

```
curl -X PUT http://admin:password@localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:jan \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \ 
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"name\": \"jan\", \"password\": \"apple\", \"roles\": [], \"type\": \"user\"}"
```

{"error":"forbidden","reason":"Doc ID must be of the form org.couchdb.user:name"}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating regular users in CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684749/creating-regular-users-in-couchdb)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this question by creating a document in _users database,

```
{
    "_id":"org.couchdb.user":username,
    "name":"username",
    "type":"user",
    "roles":[],
    "password":"plaintext_password" 
}
```

and put this above content in that document

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the colon `:` must be URL encoded.
(I figured this out by using browser dev tools to see what the UI request looks like.)

Note that the USERNAME goes both to the path and the body JSON.

```sh
# Here is an example command using cURL

echo -ne '{"name": "USERNAME", "type": "user","roles": [],"password": "PASSWORD"}' |\
  curl -X PUT "http://admin:ADMIN_PASS@127.0.0.1:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user%3AUSERNAME" -d @-

# And same with HTTPie, my favourite

echo -ne '{"name": "USERNAME", "type": "user","roles": [],"password": "PASSWORD"}' |\
  http PUT "http://admin:$COUCH_PASS@127.0.0.1:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user%3AUSERNAME"
```